# is there any ubuntu-program that you can use as mp3-player-firmware?

Tags: firmware, mp3-player

I would like to format my mp3-player (Philips GoGear 2120) with ext3 and to use a linux player on it. Does anybody know if this is possible? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Why you would do that? if you can sync your mp3 player without problem.

Comment: syncing is a problem as I can do this only as root. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You best bet would have been Rockbox but it does not have go-gear 2120 included (Philips: GoGear SA9200, GoGear HDD16x0 and HDD63x0).

Comment: thank you rinzwind, I'll have a look at rockbox, but probably there's no solution for my idea. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: no problem! But next time buy a Cowon. They support Open Source and OGG ;)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and it's not possible to change the permissions. I tried it already, but it didn't succeed.

Comment: cowon sounds interesting, but they aren't really cheap, I bet

Answer (score 2):

I had a look around and from what I could see there isn't a whole lot of custom firmware being created for Philips GoGear products, let alone an Ubuntu/Linux variant of that.

Typically, the custom firmware developers target devices they view as mainstream since then they, too, can also receive support developing various modules to get it all running butter smooth.  The real unfortunate part is that you basically need to be doing your planning prior to the purchase phase if you're looking to put something custom on the device. :/

RockBox seems to have some custom firmware for a couple Philips MP3 players, so I'm not sure how far the jump would be for them to port one of their varients, but it may be worthwhile to query them if you're set on getting some new firmware on your device.  http://www.rockbox.org/

Comment: ok, I'll have a look at rockbox. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are, no :(

I can't *personally* see any reason you would want to do this, and I doubt it would bring much benefit. As far as I'm aware there aren't many projects geared towards this sort of device as every device like it will have different components and architectures, which would make it a difficult job to achieve.

Is there any reason in particular why you'd want to do this? (NB This line was removed and then added again because it was mentioned in a comment response)

Comment: I'd recommend asking the question you posed in your answer as a comment upon the original question.

Comment: I thought of playing ogg-files instead of mp3. Thanks for your fast answering.

Comment: Ah ok, it's probably easiest to convert the ogg files to mp3, installing Linux is just too much work.